# Getting a Wicket text box's value in an AJAX onchange event

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, onchange

When a user enters a number in a Wicket text field, I need to capture the value entered on an AJAX `onchange` event. How can I do this?

Answer (score 36):

Use an [`OnChangeAjaxBehavior`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/OnChangeAjaxBehavior.html), and your component model will be updated automatically. You can query the value by using `component.getDefaultModelObject()`

```
add(new TextField<String>(id, someModel)
    .add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID =
            2462233190993745889L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(final AjaxRequestTarget target){

            // Maybe you want to update some components here?

            // Access the updated model object:
            final Object value = getComponent().getDefaultModelObject();
            // or:
            final String valueAsString =
                ((TextField<String>) getComponent()).getModelObject();
        }
    }));
```

Actually, `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` is pretty aggressive because it registers a key listener, so in most cases `new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange"){...}` will work just as well, if you just want the `onchange` event.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`, because a typical error is to just add a "regular" `AjaxEventBehavior` to a form component and then wonder why the new value doesn't appear in the model.